# Proof of infinitely many rationals "close" to a rational

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having trouble with the following homework problem:

> Suppose $a/b \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $b\neq 1$. Prove that there are infinitely many rationals $p/q$ such that $|a/b-p/q| < 1/q$. Hint: Recall that if two integers $a,b$ are relatively prime, then there exist infinitely many pairs of relatively prime integers $x,y$ such that $ax+by=1$.

In an earlier problem, I proved that if $|a/b-p/q|<1/bq$, then the rationals had to be the same; that is, $a/b=p/q$. Now we've relaxed the assumption of "closeness" to be within $1/q$. I'm not quite sure how to use the hint to arrive at the proof. Any start would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $b \ne 0$?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I believe that's just implied since $a/b\in\mathbb{Q}$. We have an additional stipulation to avoid the fixed rational being an integer.

Answer (score 5):

If you round a distance to the nearest mile, you'll be within one mile of the right answer.

Similarly among the numbers
$$
\ldots\ldots, \frac{-3}q, \frac{-2}q, \frac{-1}q, 0,\frac 1 q, \frac 2 q, \frac 3 q, \ldots\ldots
$$
if you pick the one closest to $a/b$, you'll be within $1/q$ of $a/b$.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense intuitively, and I just ran through some concrete examples and found that it holds. However, how would I turn this intuition into a rigorous proof?

Comment: If you've already defined the floor function, you could let $q\in N$ and let $p=\lfloor \frac{aq}{b}\rfloor$

Answer (score 1):

Try using the hint letting $q=x$ and $p=-y$, and show that this implies that

$aq-b<pb<aq+b$ for $b,q>0$.

Comment: Okay, I've run through some arguments and arrived at $aq-b<pb<aq+b$, but I still don't know where to go from here. I again see that, since $a$ and $b$ are fixed, that there exist infinitely many $p,q$ s.t. the inequality holds, but how to prove it?

Comment: Now you can divide by $bq$, where we can assume that $b$ and $q$ are both positive.